# Error while consuming the custom search engine google api

Tags: reactjs, axios, google-custom-search

I have a ReactJs app with a search bar and i want to consume the API custom search engine of google and im having the following error:

```
"Request contains an invalid argument."
```

The docs of the API shows the following url:

```
https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Im using the exact url but instead i paste my API_KEY without the brackets.

This is my reactjs component
Search.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Searchbar from '../molecules/Searchbar'
import { useState } from 'react';


const Search = () => {    
  
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  
  function searchInGoogle(e){
    
    const BASE_URL = `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1`
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY;
    const SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY;
    var apiCall = `${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchText}`
    axios.get(apiCall).then(function (response){
      console.log(response)
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
    
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value)
  }
  
  console.log(searchText)

  return (
    <div>
      <input className='searchInput' onChange={handleInputChange} ></input>
      <button className='btn' onClick={searchInGoogle} >Submit</button>
      {/* <Searchbar /> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Search
I tried both ways:

```
`${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY}&q=${searchTerm}`
```

and

```
`${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchTerm}`
```

In my console i get `GEThttps://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=undefined&q=asd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a project created by `create-react-app`, only [env vars](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) beginning with `REACT_APP_` are defined in `process.env`.

Change your `.env` file to include

```properties
REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY=xxxxx
REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY=xxxxx
```

You should also use Axios' `params` config to correctly and safely encode query parameters. Eg

```js
// search.js
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1";
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY;
const SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY;

export const searchInGoogle = async (searchTerm) => {
  // don't forget `await`
  const { data } = await axios.get(BASE_URL, {
    params: {
      key: API_KEY,
      cx: SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY,
      q: searchTerm,
    },
  });
  return data;
};
```

```jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import { searchInGoogle } from "./search";

const Search = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    searchInGoogle(searchText).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input className="searchInput" onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
      <button className="btn" onClick={searchInGoogle}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I ran again my server and it worked. It was just what you said before.